# Need help to implement CloseOnEscape Key Press for JQModal with IFrame

Tags: javascript, jqmodal

I am using JqModal in my project. Its a nice JS modal. However i need one help to attach an Close On Escape key press to the JqModal. I am loading eternal content from external URL in JqModal.

For simple Modal where no IFrame is used, its very easy to implement the CloseOnEscape key press feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work by updating the jqModal.js file

Steps:

1. Add option "closeOnEsc: true" to the jqModal. So the option will look something like this,

   ```
       var p = {
       overlay: 50,
       overlayClass: 'jqmOverlay',
       closeClass: 'jqmClose',
       trigger: '.jqModal',
       ajax: F,
       ajaxText: '',
       target: F,
       modal: F,
       toTop: F,
       onShow: F,
       onHide: F,
       onLoad: F,
       closeOnEsc: true
   };
   ```
2. Add following code to the jqModal open function.

   ```
       var modal = $(h.w);

       modal.unbind("keydown");

       if (c.closeOnEsc) {
           modal.attr("tabindex", 0);
           modal.bind("keydown", function (event) {
               if (event.keyCode == 27) {
                   event.preventDefault();                        
                   modal.jqmHide();
               }
           });
           modal.focus();
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

From http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-jqmodal-and-the-esc-key

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e == null) { // ie
       keycode = event.keyCode;
    } else { // mozilla
       keycode = e.which;
    }
    if(keycode == 27){ // escape, close box
       $('.jqmWindow').jqmHide();
     }
};
```

Where '.jqmQWindow' is the window or container you attached jqModal to.

Answer (score 0):

I updated user1233802's answer for the latest version of jqModal (as of 2/21/2014):

http://pastebin.com/7RQG1Jj3